# What is the noun from 'intuitional'?

Tags: intuition

I'd like to know what is the noun for 'intuitional'. I think it should be something like 'intuitionality', but with a different spelling or something. The context is about some software being intuitional(?) in usage, e.g. 'This software is good, because of its [the missing word].'. If I placed 'intuition' there, it would mean that the software is a living creature and has a sense of intuition. I tried to google this, but couldn't find anything that would fit. Could you help me?

Comment: _Intuitional_ is not exactly a normal adjective to use here in the first place. _Intuitive_ is what you’re looking for. From there, you can find the answer in any decent dictionary.

Comment: Oh, I though intuitve meant more like somebody being intuitive while making decisions. Yet you are right - I typed intuitive into my dictionary and it 'told' me that the noun for it is intuitiveness. Thanks a lot ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about **intuitiveness**? That doesn't sound unusual to me, and glancing at a dictionary shows that the *-ness* suffix applies to the word "intuitive". That's what I would use.

[(Source)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/intuitiveness)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *intuition* is the noun, *intuitive*, and *intuitional* adjectives, and *intuitionally* an adverb.

*Intuitionality*, in my view is a non-word - and to *intuition* would be like *admissionality* would be to *admission*. But thankfully I have never heard anyone utter the former.

*Intuition lay at the heart of the success in the police investigation*; *An intuitional question by the intuitive detective caught the intuitionally-bereft suspect unawares*.